# Ferramenta para medir desempenho de uma aplicação em html5 em uma plataforma android

Tags: html5

Estou interessado em criar uma aplicação em HTML5 para mobile, utilizando a plataforma android. Irei utilizar o Cordova para isso e gostaria de saber se vocês conhecem alguma ferramenta para medir o desempenho dessa aplicação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Levando em conta que é html, o desempenho fica à cargo do navegador do celular. Sendo assim, você pode usar plugins como o [YSLOW](http://yslow.org/) ou [Google Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/pagespeed/) .

Para simular smartphones existe uma extensão para chrome que pode ajudar também.

[Ripple](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc)

Answer (score 0):

Aqui nesse site você sabe o que os navegadores móveis suportam e pode ter uma base do que pode fazer: https://html5test.com/

Já verificar o desempenho vai ser meio difícil, porque cada dispositivo Android usa um `WebView` diferente para executar a aplicação em Cordova. Recomendo para testar seus apps o Phonegap Developr, claro, se vc estiver usando o Phonegap.